# Does averaging percentages of "accuracy" make sense? (example)

Tags: estimation, average, percentages, standard-deviation

In my situation, we estimate cost and then compare the estimated and actual costs to get our estimation error: actual/original estimates.

Now, does it make sense to calculate an average estimation error and its SD? I believe weighted average is not required because the "error" is the same.
The values, however, can be also negative (-100% means underestimated by 100%, while 100% means overestimated by as much).
It would be a valuable information for us allowing to set certain tresholds once we have enough data, but I struggle a bit whether there isn't an issue I am overlooking.

Comment: In general : It is not useful. **[Example A]** : When error1=+100% & error2=-100% , then over-all **average error** is 0% ! It may give the conclusion that the estimates were very accurate , whereas the estimates were wildly wrong. **[Example B]** : When error1=+90% , where we have 10 estimates & error2=+10% , where we have 1000 estimates , then over-all **average error** is +50% ! We might want over-all error to be nearer to error2 , which should have more weightage here.